# Plot PLC Background Noise

Tags: matlab, simulink, noise, time-frequency, noise-generator

I am a total newbie in signal processing. 
I have been trying to plot on simulink a time/frequency domain noise in PLC (Powerline Communication) modem that matches a real-world research, however, I failed to plot such noise. 
If anyone knows how to plot:

- In frequency domain: background noise as high as 55dB for the measurement frequency range with the power contained up to 4MHz
- In time domain: Raise up to 45dB above the background noise floor for most of the AC cycle duration

As far as the article shows, it should look like this. 
[image]

I need to plot a huge dataset, so if anyone could help me understand how to plot such noise, I will be able to plot the rest.